# I started playing on a poker site in India. Is the following scenario possible :

Tags: tournament, online

Tournament Day 1 
Player A cards : AK
Player B cards : 33
Board outcome : Player A gets one pair K ( on flop ) and player B gets 333 trips ( on turn )

Tournament Day 2 
Player C cards : AK
Player D cards :33
Board outcome : Player C gets one pair K ( on flop ) and player D gets 333 trips ( on turn )

I mean I do realize that it is possible for a hand sets and it's outcome too to repeat, a very low probability event but still possible.

But can repeat almost every night. I'm talking such hands and it's outcome being repeated almost every night in a tournament. Or is the website involved in rigging hands ?

Comment: I played a live cash game the other night. I flopped a set of 3s two times within an hour. A random occurrence within a small sample size tells you nothing really.

Answer (score 3):

If it is a shady and small site, then its quality isn't guaranteed. However the vast majority of sites aren't rigged and those who are won't survive long anyway. It is impossible for us to help you further with only this small amount of information. You can assume the site is fair unless you have strong reasons to believe otherwise.